# Second PhD and conference biographical notes

Tags: conference, second-degree

I am sending a conference proposal as a Ph.D. student. I am expected to provide a biographical note. I already hold another Ph.D. and I am not sure should I stress it or not in my biographical note. 
I was wondering what is the best practice here. Should I focus on what I am doing right now or provide information about my previous work and achievements too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biographical notes are completely your own choice to share your achievements with readers. Alongside your current work, I don't see any reason for not sharing information about your previous PhD and achievements.

Comment: Sounds good.  You can be more succinct when listing the previous PhD area work and more detailed about your recent work in your new field.